# Run `dlply` with a different function for some subsets of data in `R`

Tags: r, plyr

I have a large data for which some fits a logistic growth model and some fits an exponential growth model. I have managed to successfully calculated the nls regression parameters based on my `dlply` code to calculate parameters for each subset of my data based on three factors that can take on multiple values. However, I would like to add a constraint to use one nls form for some sets of factors as defined by another variable and another for the rest. I had thought I could use a `if … else` form but it does not seem to work.

I would really like an answer using `dlply` specifically. If it is not possible to use `dlply`, that would be helpful to know.

Here is a dummy set to illustrate what I would like to do:

```
> library(plyr)
> data(iris) iris$form<-"b" iris[iris$Species=="setosa",]$form<-"a"
> diris<-dlply(iris, as.quoted(.(Species)),
>         function(x){
>           if(x$form=="a"){
>           mean(x$Sepal.Length)
>           }else{
>             median(x$Sepal.Length)
>           }
>         })
```

splitting it into two different `dlply` functions does work but I would rather have it all tidily together:

```
diris_mean<-dlply(iris[iris$form=="a",], as.quoted(.(Species)),
             function(x){
                 mean(x$Sepal.Length)
               }
             )

diris_med<-dlply(iris[iris$form!="a",], as.quoted(.(Species)),
                  function(x){
                    median(x$Sepal.Length)
                  }
)
```

UPDATE: 
It seems my dummy example was too simple to convey what I needed. I do not understand how `summarise` or `mutate` works (from the posted answer) to be able to translate to my function. Here is the function I am using:

```
NLmodels <- dlply(cum[form=="logistic growth",], as.quoted(.(region, climate, size)), 
                  function(x)   {
                    essai=try(logis<-nls(freq~1/(1+b*exp(-(c*mid_point))),
                                         start=list(b=170,c=0.1),data=x,control=list(maxiter=200),trace=FALSE))

                    #if the nls was successful, then calculate values
                    if(class(essai)!="try-error"){
                      nls_values<-summary(nls(x$freq~1/(1+b*exp(-(c*mid_point))),
                                              start=list(b=170,c=0.1),
                                              data=x, control=list(maxiter=200)))$parameters
                    }else {
                      print("error")
                    }
                  }
                  )
```

Here is another example of what I want using an accessible dataset for just one form of a regression equation (I have two forms in my data).

```
data(mtcars)
mtcars$a_cat<-rep(c("a", "b", "c", "d"), each=8)
mtcars$b_cat<-rep(c("a", "b"), each=16)


mtcars_A<-dlply(mtcars[mtcars$b_cat=="a",], as.quoted(.(a_cat)),
                  function(x){
                    values<-summary(lm(mpg~hp, data=x))$coefficients[,1]
                  }
                  )
```

Comment: In the 'updated' code, can you also share the data with `dput`

Comment: I cannot share the data since it is team project for which I do not have permission to share, which is why I had used the `iris` dataset to create a sample problem instead of sharing my data but then you used a completely different function (which was probably appropriate for the dummy problem I posted but not something I could apply given my knowledge)

Comment: Ok, then I updated with the `iris`  example

Comment: I updated based on your new regression based code

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr`.  After splitting  by 'Species', 'form' into a `list` of data.frame, loop through the `list` with `map`, check `if` `first` element of 'form' column is 'a', then create the 'new' column as the `mean` of 'Sepal.Length' or `else` return the `median` (`map_dfr` - returns a single data.frame by row binding)

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
iris %>% 
  group_split(Species, form) %>% 
  map_dfr(~ if(first(.x$form) == 'a') {
    .x %>% mutate(new = mean(Sepal.Length)) }
  else {.x %>% mutate(new = median(Sepal.Length))})
```

---

For the regression based new example,

```
map_dfr(c('a_cat', 'b_cat'), ~
     mtcars %>% 
         group_by_at(.x) %>% 
         summarise(Coef = lm(mpg  ~hp)$coefficients[1]))
```

Or

```
map_dfr(c('a_cat', 'b_cat'), ~ 
        mtcars %>% 
           group_by_at(.x) %>% 
           do(data.frame(Coef = lm(mpg ~ hp, data = .)$coefficients[1])))
```

Comment: I think my dummy example may have been too simple... I would like to get the output to be one table with the "mean" and the "median" in the same column. The form you suggest isn't much different from running two different functions on each subset

Comment: @user3386170  are you creating a summarised column or a new column in the original dataset

Comment: I am creating a new data frame with 5 columns (for the output from nls) and about 1000 rows (for each factor combination)

Comment: Could you explain your new code a bit further? I don't understand most of how it is created.

Comment: @user3386170 added some descsripton

Comment: I don't think your code can work because I am working with a complicated function. `map` only works on vectors ("map functions transform their input by applying a function to each element and returning a vector the same length as the input")

Comment: @user3386170  In the code, I am creating a new  column (as I am not sure what you really need.  If it  needs `summarise`  replace `mutate` with  `summarise`